# How do I switch between functions every 5 seconds looped ten times?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a function that would switch the color of an element and play an audio file at the same time. Each would be for, or a pause between, 5 seconds 10 times.

Here's my code:

```
const stop = 10;
for(var i = 0; i <= stop; i++){
window.setTimeout(function() {
    $.playSound('design_tools/music/tense.m4a'); // https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound
    $( "#tight" ).toggleClass("river"); // Blue

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $.playSound('design_tools/music/release.m4a');
        $( "#tight" ).toggleClass("sun"); // Yellow
    }, 5000); 

}, 5000);


}
```

This code is what I'm looking for as in functionality, but the color change wasn't in sync with the music and it doesn't executed ten separate times. It just switches color and plays the audio files once.

** I just noticed that admsev changed his code, but I'm still using one of his earlier releases. Here it is in case you wanted to test it out:

```
/**
 * @author Alexander Manzyuk <admsev@gmail.com>
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Alexander Manzyuk - released under MIT License
 * https://github.com/admsev/jquery-play-sound
 * Usage: $.playSound('http://example.org/sound.mp3');
**/

(function($){

  $.extend({
    playSound: function(){
      return $("<embed src='"+arguments[0]+"' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' class='playSound'>").appendTo('body');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use stop as a decrementing counter and check if it is even or odd.

```
var stop = 10;

var changeColor = function(){

  if( stop % 2 === 0 ){
    $.playSound('design_tools/music/tense.m4a');
    $( "#tight" ).toggleClass("river");
  }
  else{
    $.playSound('design_tools/music/release.m4a');
    $( "#tight" ).toggleClass("sun");
  }
  stop--;
  if( stop > 0 )
    window.setTimeout( changeColor, 5000 ); 

};

changeColor();
```

Comment: This code works perfectly. I'll have to tinker with the color change/timing so that it can be in sync with the audio, but other than that it solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Stephen You are welcome. If the two sounds last for a different amount of time, you can assign the timeout delay inside the if branches.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to switch the class or sound around, but try this

```
var count=10,tId;

function toggleSound() {
  if (--count==0) {
    clearInterval(tId); // stop
    return;
  }
  $("#tight").toggleClass("river sun"); // toggle the classes
  $.playSound($("#tight").hasClass("sun")? // play matching music
   'design_tools/music/release.m4a' :
   'design_tools/music/tense.m4a');
}
tId = setInterval(toggleSound,5000);
```

Test example

```js
function playSound(sound) {
  $("body").append('<br />'+sound)
}

var count=10,tId;

function toggleSound() {
  if (--count==0) {
    clearInterval(tId); // stop
    return;
  }
  $("#tight").toggleClass("river sun"); // toggle the classes
  playSound($("#tight").hasClass("sun")? // play matching music
   'design_tools/music/release.m4a' :
   'design_tools/music/tense.m4a');
}
tId = setInterval(toggleSound,5000);
```

```css
.river { background-color:blue }
.sun { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tight" class="river">This is tight</div>
```

Comment: This makes the loop noticeably work, but it doesn't change the color, nor does it play release.m4a so I'll definitely tinker with it and see if I can get it just right. Thank you!

Comment: I had a mistake in the toggleClass, it needs a list with spaces not commas